# Trying to switch CSS properties but something is wrong with my jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on toggling the css of a div. After reading up on people attempting similar things I've put together what I thought was a valid code but when I press the shift key (key code 16) at the appropriate place (".slide" with ".active" added) nothing happens. The key here is that I mixed and matched various code I found online so maybe I'm missing something simple. My knowledge of jquery/javascript is very limited. Thanks for your help.

Here's the HTML / CSS

```
<div class="slide active loading background292929">
    <div class="drop_down_menu">
    </div>
</div>

.drop_down_menu {
    -webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { 
            $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 16) {
                $(".slide.active > div.drop_down_menu").toggle(function () {
                    $("drop_down_menu").css({
                        "display": "none"
                    });
                }, function () {
                    $("drop_down_menu").css({
                        "display": "block"
                    });
                });
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: For starters you need to add a "." in your jQuery drop_down_menu selectors

Comment: Seems like you missed class selector. $(".drop_down_menu"), Missing '.(dot)'!!

Comment: fixed that but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing **DOT** in `$("drop_down_menu")` it should be `$(".drop_down_menu")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
    $(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
        (e.keyCode == 16) && ($(".drop_down_menu").toggle());
    });
});
</script>
```

Please see the answer below:

http://jsfiddle.net/ooh7fmuy/1/

I've also simplified your code a little bit - also the `div` originally is transparent black so you can see this in action.

Comment: I see a few people pointed this out but I'll respond to yours. I added in the DOT but the toggle function still is not working. I see using chrome inspect element the `display:` property is not being changed.

Comment: I've updated my answer - please let me know if that helps.

Comment: Ok so you bound key code 16 to toggling the div. Yes that is much simpler. This works for making the div disappear. Ideally I want to toggle the CSS of the div. But for now this will work, thanks.

Comment: Oh, btw there are multiple `.drop_down_menu` classes on the site. But only the active slide has the `.active` class appended to it. I only want to effect the `.drop_down_menu` in the active slide, hence `'.slide.active > div.drop_down_menu'`

Comment: Correct `.slide.active > drop_down_menu` will work here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, toggle function accepts two arguments: `.toggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )`

But you don't need any of those.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () { 
    $(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 16) {
        $(".slide.active > div.drop_down_menu").toggle();
      }
    });
</script>
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Ok so with the .toggle() you are telling it to toggle `.drop_down_menu` on and off? I plugged that script in but still no effect.